# Sum of non-identical categorical random variables

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

Is there a named distribution for the **sum of non-identical categorical random variables**?

When the categorical variables are i.i.d., the sum is a multinomial distribution. When the categorical variables are non-identical but each have only two categories, the sum is a Poisson-binomial distribution. (If they each have only two categories and are i.i.d., the sum is of course a binomial distribution.) But what about if the categorical random variables are non-identical, independently-distributed, with three or more categories?

In addition to the name, it would be helpful if anyone is aware of any previous research on this type of distribution.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08363.pdf